# Why line != "\n" or line != "\r\n" or line !="\r" can't filte blank line?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement, blank-line

Blank line contain only `\n` or `\r\n` or `\r`.

```
tempfile = open(file,"r")
for id,line in  enumerate(tempfile):
    if(line != "\n" or line != "\r\n" or line !="\r"):
        print(id,line)
```

Why blank line can be still printed?

Comment: Try print its repr to see what is the line exactly.... and filter it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The

```
if(line != "\n" or line != "\r\n" or line !="\r"):
```

should read

```
if line != "\n" and line != "\r\n" and line !="\r":
```

i.e. using `and` instead of `or`. (I've also removed the parentheses as they are not needed in Python.)

The same expression can be written more idiomatically like so:

```
if line not in {"\n", "\r\n", "\r"}:
```

Or perhaps even:

```
if line.rstrip("\r\n"):
```

(This removes all trailing CR and LF characters and then checks whether anything remains.)